# search employees hired on specific years

Tags: sql, oracle11g

My exercise says create a query to get a list of employees hired in the period from July 1998 to December 1999. The list must contain the employee id, the last and first name and the monthly salary – given that the table contains the yearly salary and that employees get 12 salaries per year using the hr table schema.

What I've written is:

```
select employee_id, last_name, first_name, salary/12 as monthly_salary
from employees
where hire_date between ... and ... ;
```

My issue is: How should I search the hire_date with only the month and year as mentioned above eg. July 1998?

Comment: `between 01-Jul-1999 and 31-Dec-1999`? I don't really get what you're not managing.

Comment: i need to find employees hired from july 1999 till december 1999 without the day just month and year

Comment: Presumably you're deleting the details on all of your questions when they're answered so that the professor can't Google for where you found them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you have is the year and month number and are looking for the first and last dates of that month, you can find that easily with the `to_date` and `last_date` functions.

```
SQL> select to_date('2013/03', 'YYYY/MM') first from dual;
FIRST
---------
01-MAR-13

SQL> select last_day(to_date('2013/03', 'YYYY/MM')) last from dual;
LAST
---------
31-MAR-13
```

Use these functions to build your boundary dates in your query.

Note: you could also do something with `trunc(hire_date, 'MM')`, but that would probably prevent the optimizer from using an index on `hire_date`, which is not desirable.

Comment: `where hire_date between to_date(your start month) and last_day(to_date(your end month))`

Comment: You're doing something wrong, that query works as you pasted it in your comment.